# Profile Python cProfile vs unix time

Tags: python, profiling, unix-timestamp, cprofile

I am profiling a python code ; why does it spend more time in the user space ?

```
     user@terminal$ time python main.py 

     1964 function calls in 0.003 CPU seconds
```

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 :1()
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ConfigParser.py:218(**init**)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 ConfigParser.py:266(read)
       30    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ConfigParser.py:354(optionxform)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ConfigParser.py:434(_read)
       15    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ConfigParser.py:515(get)
       15    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ConfigParser.py:611(_interpolate)
       15    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 ConfigParser.py:619(_interpolate_some)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 config.py:32(read_config_data)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 config.py:9(**init**)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 entity.py:108(add_to_filter)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.002 entity.py:24(**init**)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.002    0.002 entity.py:39(create_inverted_index)
      493    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 entity.py:80(beautify)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 entity.py:84(create_bucket_lookup)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 main.py:15()
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 main.py:18()
        1    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.003 main.py:23(main)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 main.py:9(get_bag_of_words)
       19    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method group}
       34    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method match}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
       28    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'close' of 'file' objects}
       15    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       15    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'find' of 'str' objects}
       19    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'isspace' of 'str' objects}
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
       49    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
       20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'readline' of 'file' objects}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'replace' of 'str' objects}
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
       47    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
     1030    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
       15    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'update' of 'dict' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {open}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {reduce}

Done

real    0m0.063s
user    0m0.050s
sys 0m0.010s

While the cProfile says it took only 0.003 seconds, why is unix (sys) time saying it runs in 0.01 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

time(1) is measuring the execution time of the whole process, whereas the profiler excludes Python interpreter startup time, bytecode compilation time, etc.

Comment: Any reason why this is happening? http://twitpic.com/5ha6qe  In the sense why is Python taking more time in userspace ?